# How to position absolute pseudo-elements in a float context?

Tags: css

The container of my image is in float left. My content has elements with pseudo elements positioned in absolute. The floating elements are in relative position but the absolute elements do not have the right context.

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

.more {
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.more::before {
  content: 'A';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.listitems {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.listitems li {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.listitems li::before {
  content: '֎';
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="float-left">
    <img src="//via.placeholder.com/150x200" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto blanditiis corporis dolor doloremque error esse explicabo harum hic, laborum nostrum qui quisquam sit sunt, temporibus voluptates! Accusantium atque corporis doloribus illo illum iure nemo neque.</p>
    <p class="more">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto blanditiis corporis dolor doloremque error esse explicabo harum hic, laborum nostrum qui quisquam sit sunt, temporibus voluptates! Accusantium atque corporis doloribus illo illum iure nemo neque.</p>
    <ul class="listitems">
      <li>Items 1</li>
      <li>Items 2</li>
      <li>Items 3</li>
    </ul>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto blanditiis corporis dolor doloremque error esse explicabo harum hic, laborum nostrum qui quisquam sit sunt, temporibus voluptates! Accusantium atque corporis doloribus illo illum iure nemo neque.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/korigan/mygce4ds/19/)

Comment: .content {overflow: hidden;}?

Comment: No, in this case my content no longer goes under the image.

Comment: don't make them absolute, simply make them inline-block

Comment: I cannot position my elements vertically centered as in the blue block.

Comment: What if there is more content in blue, wrap under the image or keep in as a block?

Comment: First of all, you need to understand how floating actually works here. All block elements are still laid out _under_ your floated image, they still extend to the very left of the container element. Only the _inline_ content of those block items actually floats around the image. And because your LI still go over the full width, the absolute position of the pseudo child elements does not match what you expected.

Comment: Ok thx guys. So the best way is probably this one [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/korigan/mygce4ds/24/)

Comment: You figured that out, other than that use [flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/r8u7bf4a/) in .more and li is probably easier.